# Are there any Online judges which provide with users all test cases the engine uses?

Tags: algorithm

I have recently tried a problem,my code run well on the cases it presented as **sample input** however failed when I submitted, and I still haven't found the bugs. So I really hope to have some online-judges who give me all the test cases its engine use so that I can know the details when it reports such like **WA**, **RE**, **OLE**.Or It can give me a report at least telling me the code fails on which test cases.

Comment: If you knew all the test cases, couldn't you just hard-code your "solution" to return whatever the test result should be, and skip that whole annoying solving-the-general-problem thing?

Comment: @cHao Actually I don't think anyone would bother to do such a nonsense thing.

Comment: You'd be surprised.  That's actually the first thing that came to my mind when i pondered the possibility of having all the test cases laid out before me.  I probably wouldn't actually do it, but there are people even lazier than i am that would have the same idea.  If the submissions are ever ranked by speed or code size etc, it'd become even more tempting.

Comment: @cHao I do believe given all test cases people could become lazy and it's a necessity that people find (almost) all the cases that can meet a good path coverage or something like that.What I hope is that some OJs can provide with us some hints when we have tried a certain N times or other thresholds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Topcoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc) provides all the test cases. You can also check other people's solutions. It's a bit difficult to get started in Topcoder though. You'll need to run a java applet to practice / participate in Topcoder competitions. You can find the applet on top left of the page under the icon O(n). You can check the [forum](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

opc.iarcs.org.in

You can find the test cases on the main website www.iarcs.org.in

Comment: Can you give the exact link to test cases? I can't seem to find it.